# UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\QuizGame\Assets' is denied. --Unity,C#

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I'm like new in coding,I have just 2 month coding experience. So I'm writing an android quiz game and want to my quiz game to be loaded from Json file. I'm taking these errors:

```
UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\QuizGame\Assets' is denied.
System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) (at <fb001e01371b4adca20013e0ac763896>:0)
System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.IO.FileOptions options, System.String msgPath, System.Boolean bFromProxy, System.Boolean useLongPath, System.Boolean checkHost) (at <fb001e01371b4adca20013e0ac763896>:0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare,int,System.IO.FileOptions,string,bool,bool,bool)
System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding encoding, System.Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean checkHost) (at <fb001e01371b4adca20013e0ac763896>:0)
System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding encoding, System.Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, System.Int32 bufferSize) (at <fb001e01371b4adca20013e0ac763896>:0)
System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path, System.Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks) (at <fb001e01371b4adca20013e0ac763896>:0)
System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path) (at <fb001e01371b4adca20013e0ac763896>:0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(string)
System.IO.File.ReadAllText (System.String path) (at <fb001e01371b4adca20013e0ac763896>:0)
Data.Fetch (System.Boolean& result, System.String filePath) (at Assets/Scripts/Utility/GameUtility.cs:41)
Data.Fetch (System.String filePath) (at Assets/Scripts/Utility/GameUtility.cs:37)
GameManager.LoadData () (at Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs:282)
GameManager.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs:78)
```

And here is the codes i wrote:

```
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameUtility
{

    public const float ResolutionDelayTime = 1;
    public const string SavePrefKey = "Game_Highscore_Value";

    public const string FileName = "Q";
    public static string FileDir
    {
        get
        {
            return Application.dataPath + "/";
        }
    }
}
[System.Serializable()]
public class Data
{
    public Question[] Questions = new Question[0];

    public Data() { }

    public static void Write(Data data, string path)
    {
        
        using (Stream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create,FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            JsonUtility.ToJson(stream);
        }
    }
    public static Data Fetch(string filePath)
    {
        return Fetch(out bool result, filePath);
    }
    public static Data Fetch(out bool result, string filePath)
    {
        filePath = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath);
        if (!File.Exists(filePath)) { result = false; return new Data(); }

        
        using (Stream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            filePath = Application.dataPath;
            var data = JsonUtility.FromJson<Data>(filePath);

            result = true;
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for now.
If there is anything else you need just let me know.

Comment: Check that your program (or rather, the account it runs under) has permission to the folder. Nothing to do with your code, as such

Comment: Thanks dude. I tried everything in program or win 10 settings and nothing changed. I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Not sure which "win 10 settings" you mean exactly? Did you check the _permissions_ for that specific folder? Do you understand what I'm talking about?